# Foreign Key Issue ERD

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Good day folks . I am building a relational database . I am at the ERD Stage and i am having a  problem. The situation is a customer can either be representing themselves or a company  and a company might have different customers because of different departments.

the problem is i need to link the customers and company table, as to run queries such as what organisation a customer works for, but not all customers rep a company therefore i am thinking i cannot put the com_ID attribute as a foreign key in the customer table or put the c_ID in the company table because there are instances where a customer doesnt represent a org therefore the foreign key would be null in some instances which i know cannot happen...Any suggestions would be great.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: can a rep only work at one company?  The obvious solution is a denormalized table

Comment: yes a rep can only work at one company

Comment: A foreign key can be null in MySQL.

Comment: or represents themselves and not a company

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key can be null in MySQL and most DBMS.  This is why you can create an ON UPDATE or ON DELETE SET NULL.

The best solution is primarily opinion, but using com_id allowing null values would seem to work fine.  You can also set the default to null.   This would also allow you to create customers before you create companies and then assign a customer to a company, depending on your software, creating a higher degree of flexibility.

For this I would also recommend the referential integrity of ON UPDATE CASCADE, ON DELETE SET NULL.  This would allow you to keep a customer updated on the update of a company and the contact in your database should you delete a company*.

Comment: @IidsSunglassesTnt You're welcome.  If this is the answer you were looking for, please accept it as the correct answer.  If this answer just helps you in general, please consider upvoting.